# Installing kivy.garden packages (matplotlib) via a pipenv pipfile in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, kivy, pipenv, pipfile

I am trying to add `kivy.garden.matplotlib` to my **PyCharm** project.

Normally the way you would go about this is the following:

```sh
pip install kivy-garden
garden install matplotlib # can use the --app argument as well
```

However I have **PyCharm** set up to use `pipenv` so I load all my dependencies into the virtual environment via a `Pipfile`.

This works fine to install `kivy-garden` but not the garden packages. I know I can add a script to the `Pipfile` but I actually can't even get this to work properly, even within the IDE python terminal manually.

I've used the IDE terminal to try :

```
pipenv run garden install --app matplotlib
```

but this just places the files in my project directory and file paths/namespaces aren't resolved when importing (obviously). Removing the `--app` for a global install works but isn't good enough from a distribution perspective (though I can code in the meantime)

Anyone know what my options are here? Can I install the garden package through the `Pipfile` somehow? Thanks.

Comment: Hello, D.Mill, did you figure out how to do this? I'd also like pipenv to manage some  garden modules. Thank you. Regards.

Comment: forgot to tag you in last comment @D.Mill

Comment: I don’t recall managing to figure this one out sorry. I simply manually installed and called it

Comment: there's now a new approach to flowers where they can now be installed by pip/pipenv directly, without using the garden utiity. If the flower has been ported to the new model, it would then be automatically managed by pipenv as any other package. Just to let you know. Thanks.